# How many ordered triples of primes $(a, b, c)$ exist

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there any easy way to find the answer to the following problem without trying numbers one by one?

> How many ordered triples of primes $(a, b, c)$ exist such that $a+b+c=37$?

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't be hard to do a case check! W.L.O.G. $a \le b \le c$! Then $c\le 31$. Now substitute primes less that or equal to $31$ for $c$ and search for $a$ and $b$!

Comment: The whole point of the sequence of exercises is for you to list carefully. The only real shortcut is that if for example you have found that $(7,13,17)$ works, then its $5$ relatives obtained by permuting also work. A similar comment can be made for $(3,3,31)$ (two others obtained by permuting).